# SetTimeout not working when the PC screen is on locked mode in Linux

Tags: javascript, linux, electron, settimeout

I am trying to use the SetTimeout in the electron js desktop app for linux.

In that app when the user is in lock screen mode we are not getting any event for the linux and also the setTimeout function stops running in the background. Whenever the user unlocks the screen back then only the setTimeout will start running automatically.

So how can we handle that issue.

Is there any event which will emit when the user goes into the lockscreen mode in the linux or else how can we continue the setTimeout function on the lockscreen mode.

I used the events lock_screen and the unclock_screen but in the documentation it self its noted that this both the events are only for the windows and macos

Expectations :-
I should have one event with which we can get that the user is now on the lock_screen mode so we can handle by that

Or else

I should have a way to continue the settimeout function when the screen goes in the lock screen mode.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I dont have any code. I added the event which are used in the default electron js like **lock_screen** and **unclock_screen** but they are not working on linux devices